# Add Custom Field for creating new order from admin in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, layout, sales-order

I want to add new field while we create new order from the Magento admin. So, any one has any reference for this ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add a custom input field in the order form on the admin side?

Comment: @IZANOVA, Yes, I am looking for the same

Comment: can you show screenshot of where excatly you want in new field?

Comment: @IZANOVA, updated the question by adding image

Comment: in the highlighted red mark , I need the custom input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way (module) or adding your theme also works:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Data" 
             template="Vendor_Module::order/create/data.phtml" 
             name="data"
      />
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/data.phtml**
(* you can copy phtml from Magento\Sales **\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\data.phtml)** and add your field like this:

```
<section id="order-methods" class="admin__page-section order-methods">
            <div class="admin__page-section-title">
                <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Payment &amp; Shipping Information')) ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <div id="order-billing_method" class="admin__page-section-item order-billing-method">
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('billing_method') ?>
                </div>
                <div id="order-shipping_method" class="admin__page-section-item order-shipping-method">
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('shipping_method') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        //Custom Field
        <section id="order-test" class="admin__page-section test-field">
            <div class="admin__page-section-title">
                <span class="title">TEST FIELD</span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <input type="text" name="input-text" placeholder="TEST">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: this is working but when we add the whole default file phtml to our overridden phtml, it shows the content twice and also when we save the value the screen stucks.

Answer (score 1):

*emphasized text*To add a new field while creating a new order from the Magento admin in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module:

   - Create the necessary module files and directories following Magento 2's module creation process.
   - Make sure your module is enabled and registered properly.
2. Define a new field in the order form:

   - Create a new XML layout file to modify the order creation form.
   - In your custom module, create the file `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`.
   - Inside the XML file, define your new field using the `<referenceBlock>` and `<arguments>` tags.
   - Specify the field type, name, and any other attributes you require.
   - Here's an example that adds a new text field:

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_create.general.comment">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Field</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_field</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Save the new field value:

   - To save the value entered in the new field, create a plugin for the `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save` class.
   - In your custom module, create the file `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`.
   - Inside the `di.xml` file, add the plugin configuration to intercept the save action.
   - Here's an example:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save">
        <plugin name="custom_save_order_plugin"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SaveOrderPlugin"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

4. Implement the plugin logic:

   - Create the plugin class and implement the `afterExecute` method.
   - Extract the custom field value from the request and save it to the order object.
   - Here's an example:

```php
// File: Vendor/Module/Plugin/SaveOrderPlugin.php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save as SaveAction;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;

class SaveOrderPlugin
{
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(OrderRepository $orderRepository)
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function afterExecute(SaveAction $subject, $result)
    {
        /** @var RequestInterface $request */
        $request = $subject->getRequest();
        
        // Retrieve the custom field value from the request
        $customField = $request->getParam('custom_field');

        // Save the custom field value to the order object
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($subject->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'));
        $order->setCustomField($customField);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Remember to replace "Vendor" and

"Module" with your actual vendor and module names.

After following these steps and clearing the cache, you should see the new field on the order creation form in the Magento admin. The value entered in the field will be saved to the order object when the order is created.

Comment: I am trying to save using your plugin way, but it is not save the value and the process stuck. I checked the error it says "Call to undefined method getSession()"

Comment: Try with latest changes.